# JavaFX resizing to maximized each time scene changes

Tags: javafx

I'm working with javafx and scene builder to build an application. When the option `stage.setMaximized(true)` is set in the code, each time a new scene is loaded into the stage the stage will resize from a small size to maximized. I'm trying to get it so the scene will just change rather than the whole animation of resizing being shown. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just replace the root of the scene, instead of replacing the scene.

Comment: how would i go about doing that ?

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to be more precise than that without seeing any code. But call `setRoot(...)` on the scene, instead of `setScene(...)` on the stage.

Comment: brilliant...works perfectly thanks a lot!! what happens to the previous scene once a new one is set? do i need to close that scene or can i just discard it ? thanks again for your answer

Comment: Well if you use the mechanism I just mentioned, you're still using the same scene, so the question doesn't apply. But in general, a `Scene` is just like any regular Java object, if there are no references to it, it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: how can i mark comment as the answer to my question ? you've been a big help i really appreciate it man thanks again!

Comment: I will post it as an answer when I am back at my computer.

Comment: BTW, in future you will find it is much easier for people to answer your questions if you post code that illustrates the problem. In this case it would probably have been very easy to do so. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the scene, which I assume you are doing with something like

```
Parent newContent = ... ;
Scene newScene = new Scene(newContent);
stage.setScene(newScene);
```

replace the root of the existing scene, with something along the lines of

```
Parent newContent = ... ;
scene.setRoot(newContent);
```

or

```
Parent newContent = ... ;
stage.getScene().setRoot(newContent);
```